# Can a Shallow Well Jet Pump be Mounted Vertically?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

I have a 3/4 HP jet pump pulling water out of a shallow well.

It is designed with a mount that has it sitting horizontally.

Question - Is there any problem with mounting it vertically?  e.g. pipe comes out of ground vertically into pump casing input, and exits vertically out the top of the pump casing output.

Any problems which might arise from doing it this way?

Comment: How are you going to prime it? Jets loose prime and have to be filled with water. The bearing loaf and pressure on the seals will probably cause early failure.

Comment: I never have an issue with priming the lines. Honestly, each fall I unhook the entire pump and take it home from the cottage and store it inside my house. Then, each spring, I just hook it up, turn it on, and away she goes.

Comment: the manufacturer's installation manual is the deciding factor in this question

Comment: ...probably just a shallow well pump, then, not a jet pump.